# How to pass a pimpl-idiom instance from child to parent?

Tags: c++, c++98, pimpl-idiom

I have a parent class and a child class that have a Pimpl class implementation.
I want to create an instance of the pimpl in the child class and pass it to the parent by the constructor of the child to the constructor of the parent.

I tried creating a parent's constructor which takes as parameter the impl class, then calling this constructor from the constructor of the child.

```
//ParentInterface.h

class impl; //  error message is here after I add the constructor with parameter

class ParentInterface {
public:

    ParentInterface();

    ParentInterface(impl *pimpl);

    virtual ~ParentInterface();
    ParentInterface(const ParentInterface& orig);


private:
    class impl;
    impl* pimpl;

};


//ParentInterface.cpp

class ParentInterface::impl
{
  public:
    virtual ~impl(){}
    MLB_API temp[1];

  private:
};

ParentInterface::ParentInterface():pimpl(new impl()){

}

ParentInterface::ParentInterface(impl *pimpl_){
     pimpl = pimpl_;
}

ParentInterface::~ParentInterface() {
    delete pimpl;
    pimpl = NULL;
}
```

Whenever I add the constructor which takes an impl class, something goes wrong in the first `class impl;` line. The following lines are the error message

```
changes meaning of ‘impl’ from ‘struct impl’

Unable to resolve forward declaration impl
```

Comment: Declare `impl` protected rather than private if you want to use it in  a derived class.

Comment: Do you actually want two different `impl` classes? That's what you are currently expressing in the code - a `::impl` class at global scope and a `::ParentInterface::impl` class of the same name inside `ParentInterface`. Looks like the compiler shares my confusion regarding the intent...

Comment: I think it should be noted that this seems a bad idea. For example, when you call `ParentInterface::ParentInterface(impl* pimpl_)`, who owns the pointer now? `ParentInterface` will try to `delete` it on it's destructor. If you're using C++11 you should consider using smart pointers to manage ownership. Also, I think that using PIMPL and inheritance doesn't seem that good of an idea.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I do not intend to have two `impl` classes. What I want is to use the pimpl instance in the derived classes. I tried to declare pimpl as protected in the derived class but ended up with this error `invalid use of undefined type ‘struct ParentInterface::impl`

Comment: Well you have the explanation for the compiler error in question. The code you show has no derived class (there is no child and parent, despite the title), so we can't really tell you what the problem is with that code because we can't see it. You should ask a new question so as to not invalidate the answers in this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler errors are caused by 2 different `class impl`: one at the global scope, another in `ParentInterface`. `ParentInterface` constructor accepts the global `class impl`, whereas `ParentInterface::pimpl` is of type `class ParentInterface::impl`.

To fix the compiler errors, remove the global `class impl`:

```
class ParentInterface {
protected: // Accessible to derived classes.
    class impl;
    impl* pimpl;

public:
    ParentInterface();
    ParentInterface(impl *pimpl);
    ~ParentInterface();
};

class ParentInterface::impl
{
public:
    virtual ~impl() {}
};

ParentInterface::ParentInterface()
    : pimpl(new impl)
{}
```

Comment: Whenever I try to use pimpl in the derived classes, I get this error. 
`invalid use of undefined type ‘struct ParentInterface::impl`

Comment: @HasanH The derived class must have access to the _definition_ of `ParentInterface::impl`. You may like to put that definition into a header file that the derived class includes.

Comment: I can't add the defenition of `ParentInterface::impl` in a header file since I can't include `"MLB_API.h "` in any of the derived classes or header files. This is why I am using pimp.

Comment: @HasanH Then your derived class constructor must be in the same source file where `ParentInterface::impl` is defined.